# Best way to manipulate huge amount of data

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I have 160K+ documents in my mongoDB database. These are eartquakes datas and includes latitude and longitude.

The goal is fetching this data, find the location's detailed name based on latitude and longitude and add a new field to the document. So this operation should be made for each one of the documents.

I actually accomplished this task, but I'm using this approach;

```
  for (const data of eqData) {
  await main(data);
}
```

So the "main" function does everything I stated above. But it takes about 5 minutes only for 100 documents. When you calculate, it would take like a week to do this for every document.

So before this, I tried doing without awaiting but javascript simply ran out of memory and crashed.

Should I seperate the data in pieces and send request that way? For example using Promise.all() and sending 100 data at once.

thank you in advance

Comment: The question seems to lack some important details about how the data looks, and what you are doing to retrieve the detailed name. You say it's latitude and longitude, but that's ambiguous in the sense that certain solutions might allow you to retrieve a geofence for a lat-long region, and allow you to apply it across your data set, which would reduce the number of calls to a remote service.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

Comment: @Solonotix to retrieve details I make a call to another one of my databases etc. Basically it takes a lot of time to do it. But for example if I had 100 data, I could have do it all in seconds since Javascript would go out of memory.

Comment: Are you saying that the slowest part is the main() function itself? And then you ask for an advice how to speed it up providing nothing but name of the function, right? Promise.all can dramatically speed things up in some cases but it really depends on what main function does. Even with promises, it's still single-threaded js with a limited connection pool on mongo driver.  You need either profile the script and db queries yourself to identify possible vectors for optimisation or seek professional help